# How to disable AddressBookSourceSync in El Capitan

Tags: sleep-wake, contacts

`AddressBookSourceSync` continually prevents idle sleep.  I don't use address book syncing and in previous versions I used just to delete the app.  However this is now prevented by System Integrity Protection.

Is there an approved or easy way to disable the app (via a launcher or property list or something)?  Or do I have to disable SIP remove the app and then (if I can) re-enable SIP?

**EDIT**

It occurs to me that because SIP acts only on the boot disk, it is easy to delete the file by just booting from another disk (eg USB) and accessing the main HD from there.

Comment: This very much looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110828/my-macbook-wont-go-to-sleep-anymore

Comment: Hi can you elaborate on your solution? I have the same problem. Thank you

Comment: @rabbid To do this you need to install OSX on an external disk (eg a USB disk) of at least 8GB.  You can learn about that here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796  - then boot from that disk (hold option/alt when you press the power button). You can then explore the main hard disk to locate and delete the app in /Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure if this is really a good idea, but you can run this (as yourself, not root) in Terminal:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.AddressBook.SourceSync.plist
```

FWIW, I had the same problem and even after following the instructions in [Tetsujin's link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110828/my-macbook-wont-go-to-sleep-anymore), turning off all Contacts accounts in System Preferences, logging out of iCloud, blowing away the AddressBookSourceSync directories in ~/Library/Caches and ~/Library/Application Support, and of course many reboots, I could not get AddressBookSourceSync to stop blocking sleep. This command “fixed” it. AddressBookSourceSync no longer runs and `pmset -g` reports nothing preventing sleep.

You can undo the effect with this command:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.AddressBook.SourceSync.plist
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. My solution keeps getting undone by updates.

Comment: On newer versions, you need to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) first.